# Book about a woman having a magical book appear to her, she’s a witch, and a vampire stalking it

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire, witches

I remember that the book is similar to "A Discovery of Witches" by Deborah Harkness, as I thought that was the one I was looking for until I started reading it.

I honestly cannot remember the specifics but I know that it does include a vampire and witch forbidden love.

I think the female lead is a powerful witch but isn't aware of the the fact. She might be a scholar or historian, something similar I think. She recently came into possession of a magical book as it just turns up in her house/apartment. It constantly does this appearing and disappearing act.

The vampire male lead is after the book or senses the power of it and is curious. I know he is constantly appearing at her home at night, most of the time she is sleeping I think. But I remember that she can sense him. Not sure if it was an ability of hers or if it was specific to him.

I remember the book being slow paced as it laid out the history and background in detail.

Comment: How recent do you think this book was read/published? It has a few similarities with "The Invisible Library" by Genevieve Cogman is why I'm asking.

Comment: It is at least 2 years old, as it has been that long since I tried to read it.

Comment: Published 15th December 2014. Currently 99p on kindle if you are in the UK. Can't add precis as it is too long, but here's a link. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Invisible-Library-Book-ebook/dp/B00M44051E/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1548154130&sr=8-1&keywords=the+invisible+library

Comment: Thank you for the link. But this is not the book I am looking for. The Mc is not yet that involved with supernatural either through lack of interest or lack of awareness. It doesn't have a focus on a library.